# SDL Web 8: Topology Manager, error using Add-TtmMapping

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I have been messing around with Topology Manager recently.

I have a problem with the `Add-TtmMapping` powershell command.

I get the following error message:

```
"Item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' with id 'SDLWebTridioncm_MAN01SQL05' does not exist"
```

Digging into this, it appears that Topology Manager doesn't have any information about CmEnvironmentData in its database. Which is weird.

[image: Empty Topology Manager CmEnvironmentData]

So I reckon I've missed a step somewhere or something hasn't installed correctly. Anyone able to shed any light on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The installer created the "SDLWebTridioncm_MAN01SQL05" CM environment for you (it asks you for the name in one of the screens). Since then, apparently someone decided to clear or recreate your Topology Manager database -- so it lost the information again. The Topology Manager website hasn't been restarted either, so it thinks it still exists.

Anyway, since you have a clean database you'll want to recreate this CM environment through the `Add-TtmCmEnvironment` cmdlet. I recommend using the same name so you don't have to modify anything else. You may have to restart the Topology Manager website first.